# What is this weird ObjectID in Firefox's spki export of an EC public key?

Tags: javascript, firefox, elliptic-curve, webcrypto-api

Given an spki export of an EC public key (code at bottom), Chromium & co give off a sane ObjectID but Firefox gives off a completely different one:

```
  0  86: SEQUENCE {
  2  16:   SEQUENCE {
  4   4:     OBJECT IDENTIFIER '1 3 132 112'wat
 10   8:     OBJECT IDENTIFIER prime256v1 (1 2 840 10045 3 1 7)
       :     }
 20  66:   BIT STRING
       :     04 EB F3 46 9A 56 19 D6 76 36 23 3B 57 D4 01 25
       :     CD DD A4 BF 72 DF 51 C7 E7 AA 81 B9 04 5F DF 6B
       :     CA 02 E4 3E 02 D1 44 57 65 EB 9E 36 C4 79 A6 F8
       :     51 BB 2D 8F DC C4 42 B3 DB 8B A3 AF 57 F0 BF 7B
       :     35
       :   }
```

For reference, here's one extracted from Chromium:

```
  0  89: SEQUENCE {
  2  19:   SEQUENCE {
  4   7:     OBJECT IDENTIFIER ecPublicKey (1 2 840 10045 2 1)yes thank you
 13   8:     OBJECT IDENTIFIER prime256v1 (1 2 840 10045 3 1 7)
       :     }
 23  66:   BIT STRING
       :     04 9D 16 97 2F 89 6F 9B 87 4B 86 0E F7 8F BB 98
       :     37 E2 BF 75 7C 8E AD 1C A7 B4 5F 6D 75 72 90 FC
       :     8F 30 AF 91 4B AA 96 71 F3 52 6B 58 8F E0 27 92
       :     13 12 77 D1 17 76 F3 3A FD ED A9 B1 1A 64 5E 5F
       :     B1
       :   }
```

(Dumps generated with [`dumpasn1`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/dumpasn1/))

And indeed, going on [OID ref](https://oidref.com/1.2.840.10045.2.1) Chromium's identifier seems good.
Firefox's OID seems to belong to [another group entirely](https://oidref.com/1.3.132) and I cannot even find it.

The thing is, a different OID makes various imports crash. A key exported this way from Firefox cannot be imported into OpenSSL or even Chromium without being altered first.

Thus,

1. What is this ID?
2. Why does Firefox use it instead of the more "standard" one used by Chromium?
3. Speaking of standards, is there anywhere this export format is defined in the [W3C Recommandation](https://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/) or a related RFC?

---

Here's a snippet to quickly generate an exported EC public key:

```js
(async () => {
  const subtle = crypto.subtle
  const eckp = await subtle.generateKey({
    name: 'ECDSA',
    namedCurve: 'P-256'
  }, true, ['sign', 'verify'])

  const exportedPubK = new Uint8Array(await subtle.exportKey('spki', eckp.publicKey))
  console.log(exportedPubK.length) // 88 for the weird OID, 91 otherwise.
  console.log(`[${exportedPubK.join(', ')}]`)
})();
```

---

## Important note

This question is stale as of the resolution and closure of [this Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1410403). Firefox 72 should no longer display this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause is a Firefox-bug, see [Bug 1410403](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1410403) and [Bug 1514032](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1514032), respectively.
The correct OID for a public ECDSA (or ECDH) key is `1.2.840.10045.2.1` according to [RFC 5480, section 2.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5480#section-2.1.1). OID `1.3.132.112` is not defined (the similar OID `1.3.132.1.12` is restricted to ECDH, see also [RFC 5480, section 2.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5480#section-2.1.2) and [W3C Recommendation, section B](https://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/#spki-mapping)).